# CTFontManagerUnregisterGraphicsFont returns true but memory not released

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-text

`CTFontManagerUnregisterGraphicsFont(cgFont, &fontError)` returned true so I expect that:

1. `cgFont` be released from memory (The registered font is a Japanese font over 5MB!)
2. Calling `[UIFont fontWithName:postscriptName size:fontSize]` afterwards should return `nil`

But `cgFont` behaves as though it was not unregistered.

Is this behavior expected?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expectations don't match my understanding of the documentation. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_FontManager_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008278-CH3-SW23) say that "Registered fonts are discoverable through font descriptor matching." "Unregistered fonts are no longer discoverable through font descriptor matching." That's all it means.

When you're done with a `CGFont`, you should call `CGFontRelease()`. You should only unregister a font if you also registered it.

Comment: Thanks. Already called CGFontRelease(). But __bridge ARC object is not released. In the sample the WWDC Sample code "CustumFonts", has been resolved. About 2. return not nil. But returned UIFont used crash. Thanks for Advise!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithName:fontName size:size] size:size];
```

But don't use the following code:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:postscriptName size:fontSize]
```